# Is there a certain type of LDR that will be most effective in a circuit that senses the heartbeat at a fingertip?

Tags: photoresistor

I haven't had much experience with LDRs, and was not sure of the different types that will work best in a circuit like that.

Comment: Maybe you can explain how an LDR can measure heartbeat?

Comment: the LDR is the input to an op-amp set up as a comparator, that will go high whenever there's a change in the input signal (AKA when the blood flows in/out of your finger)

Comment: Do you have luminous or light-emitting blood? I don't (last time I checked) so it wouldn't work for me.

Comment: ahaha, no, when there's blood flow, there's less apparent light than when there isn't. I'm sure this can be explained better if you google search how heart-beat sensors work.

Comment: http://www.raviyp.com/embedded/140-learn-how-a-heart-beat-sensor-works - your design appears to be lacking a vital component (apparently).

Comment: was the fact that there's a LED not obvious...?

Comment: Of course I knew there had to be a light source but your (unspecified) light source has much to do with whether an LDR can work or not. Your profile doesn't tell me if you are an idiot so I asked the question AND, if you want an answer try delivering more details.

Comment: Red LED, 120 mcd.

Comment: Have you uncovered an LDR that works optimally at the light wavelength used? Have you also considered that a more sophisticated approach is to pulse the laser in the tens of kHz region so that the "detector" can "rule out" the effects of ambient lighting? This would tend to rule out the fairly sluggish LDR.

Comment: I did not consider that approach... Thanks

Comment: IR works better than red.

Comment: @MenaLabib - If the idea of using an AC signal to ignore background light levels interests you, look up "phase-sensitive detection" and "lock-in amplifier".

Answer (score 4):

LDRs are very slow and not very sensitive. Use a phototransistor, ideally one matched to the wavelength of your light source. As Andy mentioned, to reject interference from ambient lighting, you may want to modulate your light source so you can filter out ambient rubbish.

Comment: LDR corner frequency is typically hundereds of hertz or better. plenty for measuring a heartbeat.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for TCRT1000 opto-electro sensor, which is reflective opto sensor, So you can measure your heartbeat rate. Don't forget to add filters on the output stage